# Large space between two iFrames (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

So I have this simple [website called Quest Talk](https://questtalk.neocities.org) (questtalk.neocities.org)

Between the Google Form and the Substack Form there is a weird user-unfriendly space. However it is only visible on desktop browser apps and not on mobile browser apps. There is no specific CSS setting. (See full CSS code below)

**My question:** How can I make sure that space is used as efficiently as possible and there is not such a huge gap between the two frames?

**My code:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-bottom: 2rem; /* Add margin */
}

header h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#language-container {
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-style: italic;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
}

#question-container {
  background-color: #1B3B3A;
  color: white;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  font-size: calc(2.0*(0.75vh + 0.8vw));
  /* padding: 2rem; */
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50vh;
}

#refresh-btn {
  background-color: #1B3B3A;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}


/* .arrow {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
} */

#about-container {
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  /* padding: 1rem; Add padding */
}

#legal-container {
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  color: #1B3B3A;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  font-style: italic;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 2vh solid #1B3B3A;
  height: 1vh;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #1B3B3A;
  /* This sets the color of unvisited links */
}

a:visited {
  color: #1B3B3A;
  /* This sets the color of visited links */
}

a:hover {
  color: #1B3B3A;
  /* This sets the color of links when the mouse is over them */
}

a:active {
  color: #1B3B3A;
  /* This sets the color of links when they are clicked */
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScKB_z1KgvVb9YI8TsqxESmbC8ls1vEfvv_9oJMD6O1g6gc3Q/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="790" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe> To stay up to date and show support,
click 'Subscribe'
<iframe src="https://questtalk.substack.com/embed" width="100%" style="border:0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
              </iframe>
```

I used `<br>` and `<p>` but that did not make a difference at all on Desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in that the upper `iframe` has height set to `790`, and that value highly exceeds the size of HTML document inside. For example if you set the height to `630`, the space will be much smaller.

It's not possible to set the height based on content height of `iframe` content purely with CSS, the only solution would be getting the content height using JavaScript by accessing the content with `myIframe.contentDocument`, however your `iframe` is cross-origin so this won't work. Another solution would be with `postMessage()`, but you can't control the content of `iframe`.

So, for now you'll need to use an absolute height.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
body {
     background-color: #D6FFC7;
     color: #1B3B3A;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
   font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
  text-align: center;
  
  /* margin-bottom: 2rem; /* Add margin */
}

header h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}


#language-container {
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-style: italic;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
  }

#question-container {
background-color: #1B3B3A ;
color: white;
/* font-weight: bold; */
font-size : calc(2.0*(0.75vh + 0.8vw)) ;
/* padding: 2rem; */
text-align: center;
margin-left: 0;
display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50vh;
}

#refresh-btn {
  background-color: #1B3B3A ;
  color: white ;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 1em ;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer ;
  border:none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

/* .arrow {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
} */

 #about-container {
   background-color: #D6FFC7;
   color: #1B3B3A;
/* padding: 1rem; Add padding */
} 

#legal-container {
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  }


footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D6FFC7;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #1B3B3A;
  font-style: italic;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 2vh solid #1B3B3A;
  height: 1vh;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #1B3B3A; /* This sets the color of unvisited links */
}

a:visited {
  color: #1B3B3A; /* This sets the color of visited links */
}

a:hover {
  color: #1B3B3A; /* This sets the color of links when the mouse is over them */
}

a:active {
  color: #1B3B3A; /* This sets the color of links when they are clicked */
}
```

```html
<iframe    src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScKB_z1KgvVb9YI8TsqxESmbC8ls1vEfvv_9oJMD6O1g6gc3Q/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
        To stay up to date and show support, click 'Subscribe'
        <iframe src="https://questtalk.substack.com/embed" width="100%" style="border:0" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no">
              </iframe>
```

**Explanation:**

Simply the first `iframe` `height` is set to `790` which is more than the form needs hence the gap created by the first `iframe` expanding on the lower side.

I just changed the height to `600` instead so it takes as much space as it need.